# Lex: C keyword rules not identifying correctly

Tags: c, keyword, flex-lexer, lex

I wrote a simple lex file to identify C keywords.  My rules looks like:

```
keyword do|while|char|if
%%
{keyword}  { printf("Keyword %s found.", yytext); }
```

The problem is the rule correctly identifies `char` in source code, but it also identifies things like `putchar` as keyword `char`.  How can I force the rule to only identify the keyword `char` and not when it's present in other words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put keywords before identifiers. That's all. Lex is searching for regular expressions sequentially.

```
%%

IF|ELSE|etc {action for keywords }

[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]* {action for identifiers}

%%
```

Comment: What have I said wrong? Comment for minus would be nice. Because this is exactly answer to his question.

Comment: Actually, this solved part of the problem.  Why the down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Your lexer has to match other things (including something that will match the "put" substring) to allow it to distinguish between keywords and non-keywords.

If I were writing the lexer, I would simplify it by matching possible identifiers and using a lookup table to identify keywords in the resulting tokens.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So take any identifier found and compare it to a keyword lookup table?  Kind of like a symbol table?  I'm wondering why something as simple as `"char" { return(CHAR); }` is used here then: http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html

Comment: It "works", but is less general than an approach separating syntax and data.  I mostly use `lex` for syntax highlighters, and avoid mixing data in the lexer.